# How can I write this jQuery statement shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code. This works perfect but I just wanna know if it's possible to write it shorter or not? I looked at jQuery [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) docs but didn't find anything useful.

```
$(this).hasClass('nw')
     ?'nw'
     :$(this).hasClass('ne')
          ? 'ne'
          : $(this).hasClass('sw')
               ? 'sw'
               : $(this).hasClass('se')
                    ? 'se'
                    : false ;
```

Comment: No offense, but this line of code is **horrible**. At least give it some parentheses and wrapping so it's readable. Besides that, you might want to use the raw class name available via `$(this).attr('class')` and use custom code to extract the value from it.

Comment: `$(this)` store into variable once, use variable multiple times!

Comment: I was going to post this as an asnwer, but ti's not really an aswer... I don't think you can. You have written it in a very compact (and currently unreadable) way. Notice that if there is more than one of those class you might not get the results your looking for

Comment: I'll take readability over shortness.

Comment: @Kris - i'll take efficentcy ;)

Comment: It's most efficient code

Comment: @mohen - see my answer there is a more efficent way

Comment: May I ask why your interested in how many characters you use to write your code?

Comment: @kralco626 - he is a human compressor. No need for build scripts!

Comment: @Mohsen, I updated my answer with an example for concrete evidence.

Comment: @epascarello - Don't think he would do a very good job seeing as how it has taken two hours to figure out how to compress one line of code... lol

Comment: Regardless of what you are doing with the result of this expression, there is a better way. I can't give a solid answer until I see more code (what are you doing with this string and why?)

Comment: I have four handles around an element for scaling. I want to check which handle is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular Expression:**

```
var str = $(this).attr('class')
var re = /(\s|^)(nw|ne|sw|se)(\s|$)/
var theClass = str.match(re);
var handleCorner = theClass ? theClass[2] : null;
```

And just for that length comment: [count this!]

```
var a=$(this).attr('class').match(/(\s|^)(nw|ne|sw|se)(\s|$)/);
handleCorner=a?a[2]:null;
```

**The best performance code is**

```
var elm = $(this);
elm.hasClass('nw')
     ?'nw'
     :elm.hasClass('ne')
          ? 'ne'
          : elm.hasClass('sw')
               ? 'sw'
               : elm.hasClass('se')
                    ? 'se'
                    : false ;
```

[Performance tests](http://jsperf.com/test-performance-of-has-class) with all of the solutions

Comment: I'd use \W instead of the parenthesis before and after the two letters.

Comment: Mine is 126Char your is 146! ;)

Comment: @Mohsen as if yours was readable?  That's not a very good argument.

Comment: See also http://jsperf.com/test-performance-of-has-class/2 for tests against `attr('data-direction')` and `data('direction')`.

Comment: @mohsen, I just want to note that this proves that cashing $(this) is more efficient than not. It can preform 30% more operations per second.... Just to counter your comment on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = $(this)
["ne","nw","sw","se"].filter(function(d) { return t.hasClass(d) })[0]
```

Comment: if you need the fall through case of `false`, then at the end of put `|| false`, otherwise you'll get `undefined` (which is still falsey)

Comment: filter is not supported everywhere

Comment: fair enough, its not supported in ie<=8. but that's the way I'd do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use `data` attributes to store things as data.** It looks like you are keeping track of directions.  While you might want to style directions in some particular way, you really should keep your direction in a `data-*` attribute, perhaps `data-direction`.  Then you can know what direction it is, and still base a class off it.

Hit me up if you want to see an example.

---

**Example:**

```
var direction = $(this).attr('data-direction');

//or slower, but more accurate:
var direction = $(this).data('direction');
```

Was not that shorter, and faster performing?  (Hint: yes and yes).  After reading your comments on other posts, those are your goals.  Man up and mark up, I say.

Comment: I know how to use data attribute. I don't want to add more mark up

Comment: @Mohsen Then you are probably thinking incorrectly.  Your jQuery code will be much longer and perform slower having to deal with parsing the className to get which direction it is.  It's obviously your choice, but I'll choose semantics.

Comment: @Levi - I agree with you, using classes to store data it not a great idea.

Comment: I'm using classes for both styling and detecting direction. So this solution is not best solution for me.

Comment: @Mohsen I will continue to disagree: they created `data-*` for a reason.  It's simple: update your mark-up, use `data-direction` when you want to know what direction it is, and if you need to change the class, call removeClass on the current direction, change the property, then add the new property.  It's the correct way to go, and still performs quickly.  What are you so shy about?

Comment: I use data attribute in my code. I don't think this is best solution. I up voted your answer but that is not the right answer to my question IMO

Comment: @Mohsen Your question was: How can I write this jQuery statement shorter? And I took the purpose and gave you a shortened response that's semantically correct. I'm concerned with your thinking behind your coding, which is why I've still been pushing this.  I've tried enough to convince you.  I'm done. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry Levi, don't take these personal. We're both professionals that are discussing about a technical issue. I said IMO. Maybe most of people here agree with you...

Comment: @Mohsen, Oh, I haven't taken it personally.  I'm just not going to push it anymore.  If you don't want my answer, you don't have to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update** - this is wrong, I'd remove it, but there is an alternative in the comments by [32bitkid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373378/32bitkid) that you might want to check out.

I think your code is pretty concise and readable.  If you want to shave off a few characters, you can do something like:

```
var hc = $(this).hasClass;
handleCorner = hc('nw') ? 'nw' :  hc('ne') ? 'ne' : hc('sw') ? 'sw' : hc('se') ? 'se' : false ;
```

Comment: Saving hasClass in a variable is awesome

Comment: This is proly the best solution here...bester than mine because it stores the function too...

Comment: I tested this. You can't save hasClass in a variable

Comment: you can, but you would have to do `var hc = $.proxy($(this).hasClass, $(this))`

Comment: You can store anything in a Javascript variable, but that doesn't necessarily make it perform better...

Comment: You're right.  Gotten too used to writing out Python.  Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can shorten it significatly and keep the same meaning.

You have written it in a very compact way.

For efficency you should save $(this) as a variable

```
$this = $(this);

$this.hasClass('nw')
     ?'nw'
     :$this.hasClass('ne')
          ? 'ne'
          : $this.hasClass('sw')
               ? 'sw'
               : $this.hasClass('se')
                    ? 'se'
                    : false ;
```

The other solutions make the likly incorrect assumption that there are no other classes.

Notice that with your solution if there is more than one of those class you will only get the first one you find, not all of them. Not sure if thats your intention.

Comment: For efficency you should save $(this) as a variable. $(this) in jQuery is not like $(DOM). It's efficient enough

Comment: I did save $(this) as a variable, thats the whole point... you want me to say "var $this = $(this)" ? not sure what you mean...

Comment: @Mohsen, you are incorrect `$(this)`, this is same exact lookup as having the `$(DOM OBJECT)`. Both have to create the jQuery object. It is faster than `$("selector")`

Comment: @epascarello - thank you, I mentioned as a comment to your answer that your preformance tests proved this. I like that site, it's really cool, i'll have to keep that one in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary shorter, but more clear and extensible:

```
 handleCorner = false;
 for (i in a = ['nw','ne','sw','se']) {
   if ($this).hasClass(a[i]) {
     handleCorner = a[i];
   }
 }
```

Comment: And you do not break after finding the first value